# iPad UI design options

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface

I have an app that main layout is a custom top bar (with actions similar to a web browser, back, forward, etc.), a left main menu and a center view where all the information is displayed.

So at first I think of this app as a Master-Detail one but the top bar and the navigation options seems to prevent this option.

Then I remember the view controllers containment option. Basically I will try to build the root view controller with a view representing the top bar, a table view as the main menu and in the central view add the child view controllers. This option also allows me to build view controllers with similar layout (left menu and center display view).

The truth is that I'm not 100% sure that this is the better option, so I'm asking here if anyone has experience with something like this and if you think this is the best option to build this kind of layout.

Cheers!

**EDIT1:** Here is an image that represent the layout. In the content view there could be other views similar to a Master-Detail view.

[image]

Comment: Could you add an image showing what you want?  We would be able to better guide you then....

Comment: @Inafziger sure, check the post with an image about the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create it like this:

Start with a UINavigationController.

This will allow you to use the UINavigationBar at the top in order to get your Top Menu Bar.

Then, create a custom UIViewController which contains a UITableView and a UIView (not controllers) and push it onto the navigation stack.  This allows you to control both views from the same controller, making interaction between them trivial.

On the other hand, if you need to swap out the right or left views a lot and want them to be "stand-alone" then you will be better off using view controller containment as you initially thought.  This is slightly more involved, but the UIView class reference has very good documentation on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @inafziger. The deal is that the top bar is used as a navigation bar for forward and backward movement, so i think that the second option is better. Also, the content is very complex so i think that I'm going to make a root view controller with a table view and a top bar (hand made, as a view with different buttons) and a central view where to load the viewcontrollers with the content. Sounds good?

Comment: Well, the UINavigationBar is intended for forward/back navigation and other buttons so I would still consider using it, even if using the second option.

Comment: @Inafziger Ok but in that case the UINavigationController will be useless, right?

Comment: But my left bar should stay all the time and only the "Real content" part will change, correct me if i'm wrong but if i use a UINavigationController can't reproduce this behaviour right? (@Inafziger sorry for so many questions but i want to understand and make this right)

Comment: No worries. You can add custom buttons to a nav bar that do anything that you want, or since only the content in the right view controller is changing, you can make it a nav controller and push/pop view controllers only in that portion of the screen. (I do this in one of my apps, and have an empty nav bar on the left for appearance).

Comment: How can i make the navcontroller to load only on a part of the screen? Because i always see them working on the entire screen.

Comment: That's because there is usually only one view controller per screen.  If you are using view controller containment, then you can have your "content" view controller (the right one) be a nav controller, which contains your view controller(s).  The same can be done with your left view.  Make it a nav controller which contains a table view controller (if you want the nav bar there too, even if only to make it visually match your right view controller).

Comment: @Inafziger tks a lot, i could make it with containment and seems to work well.